# Is there a way to add a single set to an array using loop in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I just want to make the elements as one index.

This is where I will store the data:

```py
array = []
```

This is my code:

```py
for x in range(2):
  array.append({data[x]})
```

The result of this code is `array = [{data1},{data2}]`. 
I just want to make it as `array = [{data1, data2}]`.

Comment: It is not clear how these two shall relate. Do you just want to have an array of tuples, e.g. [('a', 'b')]? What is the dictionary for?

Comment: No, not an array of tuples. The dictionary is made to display datas in a django serializer(as response). I was trying to filter a lot of fields so I have to store them as one because they have a lot of foreign key fields.

Comment: btw the type of `array_of_dict` is a `list` with a `set` in it.

Comment: Please clarify your question, see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: I've updated the question to Clarify it.

Comment: your question is still not clear, sorry... The code is not reproducible. Also, what do you mean by `{data1}` and by `{data1, data2}` ? Curly braces like this denote a `set` in python so no dictionary. If there is just a single set, then why would you need a `for` loop to add it to the array ? Just create the set first, and then add it as the unique element in your list.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear but I will try to guess what you're after.

If you use a list as a key in a dictionary you get an exception:

```
array = ['a', 'b']
dct = {array: 'val'}
```

yields

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

This is because a list is mutable and therefore the dictionary might misbehave if you modify your list after it has been used as a key.

Therefore to circumvent this you can transform the list into a tuple which is immutable:

```
dct = {tuple(array): 'val'}
print(dct)
```

yields

```
{('a', 'b'): 'val'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `tuple`s can be the index used in a `dict` because it is hashable whereas some other types cannot:

```
array = ['a', 'b']
tup = tuple(array)

#This works:
d = { tup:'A Value'}

#This does not work:
d = {array:'A Value'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var1 = {'a':'12ab...' , 'b': 235 }
var2 = {'d1' : "28-03-2020" }
arr = [var1   , var2 ]

print(arr[0]) >>> {'a':'12ab...' , 'b': 235 }

print(arr[1])  >>> {'d1' : "28-03-2020" }

print (arr[0]['a'])  >>> 12ab...
```

does this satisfy you ?